# Conditonally return different REST API response object for same endpoint

Tags: rest, asp.net-core-webapi, api-design

The following scenario does not follow RESTful standards and would be keen to know how best to structure my API to achieve the same goal.

For a given GET request against a resource, e.g. `GET /api/person/1`, if the principle contains a claim I would like to return additional properties.

E.g.

```
GET /api/person/1 (Without IsAdmin claim)
{
  name: "Buck Rogers",
  dateOfBirth: 2000-01-01T00:00:00.000
}
```

```
GET /api/person/1 (With IsAdmin claim)
{
  name: "Buck Rogers",
  dateOfBirth: 2000-01-01T00:00:00.000,
  adminNote: "Something private"
}
```

So I'd conditionally be returning two different DTOs for the same resource request, which isn't allowed.

How can I achieve this in a RESTful way?

**Update:**

It was suggested I could define the `adminNote` property and NULL it based on the condition. How would I deal with the case where there might be multiple conditionals that determine which properties are included? E.g.

```
GET /api/person/1 (With IsModerator claim)
{
  name: "Buck Rogers",
  dateOfBirth: 2000-01-01T00:00:00.000,
  moderatorNote: "Something else private"
}
```

I would be keen to avoid adding extra properties that will only ever not be null in one particular case.

Comment: I'm not sure this goes against REST: you're still producing the same resource (a "person"), just the representation of it changes depending on the caller. If documenting this API, you could simply flag `adminNote` as "_optional, valued only for admins_" or something along those lines.

Comment: I agree with @sp00m. Could you provide us with the information where you found it is going against REST principles?

Comment: I couldn't find anything absolute that gave an answer either way. In my mind a RESTful API should be deterministic given an identical request. I appreciate what you're saying, that both responses are logically a Person resource, but I'd be returning a different DTO type based on the condition. I did read that OpenAPI/swagger doesn't support this.

Comment: Yes, OAS 3 does support that FYI, thanks to `anyOf` for instance, see https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/oneof-anyof-allof-not/. Whether you use two distinct DTOs or a single one with optional fields though is a very technical concern IMHO, I'm not sure REST goes that deep in the implementation details. I still see a single resource personally. I get your point though, interested to see other opinions about that :)

Comment: But it's quite obvious the path `/api/person/1` suits both cases, meaning we're actually representing the same resource. If this really bothers you, you could still have a query param `view` that would take `minimal` or `detailed` for instance, but then it's more job for the callers, plus again, it's a very "technical param" (maybe more the job of a header, e.g. `Accept`?). I wouldn't bother too much though personally, a well written documentation should do the job :)

Answer (score 0):

you can create a Person resource with all the three fields and when the IsAdmin is false or without claim , you could set adminNotes to null.And to not return that property you can use `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` (its for java, something like this might be available in asp.net) as well.So you don't need to create two separate entities or DTO's.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, however I'd prefer to explicitly define the response objects. My question is obviously a very simplistic example, but say I had 10 conditionals, all of which resulted in different properties being included, I don't think this approach would be very tidy.

Comment: @ChrisPickford just came across this as I had a similar requirement to achieve. I know it has been quite sometime, but do you remember what approach you had taken? Thanks.